# Restore a deleted PLESK subscription

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh, plesk, data-recovery

I just deleted a plesk subscription thinking I could restore it from my backup. It looks however like the backup for that subscriptions is not there.

Is there anything I can do to restore a recently deleted subscription? Or recover the mySQL database through SSH or something?

Thanks

Henry

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its bad to delete subscription in plesk .

Can you contact your hosting provider to check if they have valid backups for your VPS or the server that your PLESK is on it ?

If you dont use any backup or backup plesk solutions the only good (best) chance is to check with the hosting provider .

Answer (score 0):

If you have created backup for subscription on subscription level and delete it, you can create new subscription with same name and all previously created backup will be in subscription backup repository.